# Htaccess hide url parameter key

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Currently what i have done in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#####exclude /admin88 folder####
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin88
#################
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /((?!admin88)[^.]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [NC,L,QSA,R=301]
```

To hide .php in all pages but exclude /admin88 directory which is working perfectly

Next what i need from following url

```
www.example.com/page_name/?lang=en
or
www.example.com/?lang=en
```

To hide ?lang from the url based on my existing htaccess

```
www.example.com/page_name/en
or
www.example.com/en
```

I have tried to change my htaccess but it mess up alot

Comment: "from following url" - You seem to have this bit in reverse? You should have already changed the URL from `/page_name/?lang=en` to `/page_name/en` in the application itself. You then use mod_rewrite to internally rewrite the URL from `/page_name/en` back to `/page_name/?lang=en`. However, `/page_name/?lang=en` isn't actually the true end-point - what is the filesystem-path/script that actually handles the request?

Comment: Right now my website showing this www.example.com/?lang=en but i need to hide the ?lang

Comment: Ok, but you need to change that in the HTML source, not `.htaccess`.